# How to make signalObjectAndWait an atomic operation

Tags: c++, multithreading, scheduled-tasks

I build up a scheduler system that schedule tasks between multiple threads.

I have a single thread that handle the scheduling operation on top of a queue and a job  thread that would be execute on a system.

The job threads enters itself to the queue and signal the scheduler thread to begin its operation, BUT  before the job thread gets the opportunity to enter wait signal, the scheduler thread start working and send an event signal to the original  job thread, unfortunately only then the job enters a wait operation instead of working.

What I was meant to do:

@ Job signal to the scheduler thread and enters wait mode

@ Scheduler start working and signal the job thread

@ job thread start working

Instead , what is actually happens:

@ Job signals to the scheduler thread

@ Scheduler start working and signal the job thread

@ job thread enters wait state

I tried using "signalObjectAndWait" command , but according to MSDN:

> Note that the "signal" and "wait" are not guaranteed to be performed as an atomic operation. Threads executing on other processors can observe the signaled state of the first object before the thread calling SignalObjectAndWait begins its wait on the second object.

Is there any way to grantee that signal and wait operation would be atomic?

Comment: Use a semaphore for the Wait object?  The semaphore maintains a count state and so it does not matter if the signal happens before the wait - it will still be handled correctly.

Comment: I didn't use a semaphore for the wait  \ signal operation, then I would not be able to use inhibit windows API events